# Custom data plugin

Tags: wordpress

I often deliver wordpress pages because it's easy to setup. When I don't, it's often because the customer need custom data. For example a car dealer would want a data type for car models, car windows and car doors - all with different attributes. These should be editable in the Wordpress admin and also somewhat easy to print out with a foreach loop to the frontend.

I found the plugin Custom Database Tables (https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-database-tables/) but I would also need relationships between the different tables. If I configure five different car doors, I would want them listed as a select box when I edit a car for example. It doesn't seem to support that?

Is there any alternatives from creating my own plugin for this? Seems like such an ordinary case for non blogs?

Thanks.